# Extract particular character using StandardSQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to extract particular character from strings using `StandardSQL`.
I would like to extract the character after `limit=`.

For instance, from below strings I would like to extract 10, 3 and null. For everything that has null I also would like to make all null = 1.

```
partner=&limit=10

partner=aex&limit=3&filters%5Bpartner%5D

partner=aex&limit=&filters%5Bpartner%5D
```

I only know how to use substring function but the problem here is the positions of `limit=` are not always the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [REGEXP_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_extract). For example:

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('partner=aex&limit=3&filters%5Bpartner%5D', 'limit=(\\d+)');

+-------+
| $col1 |
+-------+
| 3     |
+-------+
```